# PHP: Load data infile with sprintf got problem with '%' when converting the date format

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to load csv file using this but the date format is incorrect which I need to reformat before inserting to database

```
if (is_array($file)) {
    foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
        $loadData = sprintf("
            LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' IGNORE INTO TABLE pos_vs_cognizant CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES  
            (
                @store, 
                @business_date, 
                @ns_pos, 
                @ns_cognizant, 
                @ns_variance, 
                @tc_pos, 
                @tc_cognizant, 
                @tc_variance
            ) 
            SET
            id=null,
            store=@store,
            business_date=STR_TO_DATE(@business_date, '%d-%b-%y'),
            ns_pos=@ns_pos,
            ns_cognizant=@ns_cognizant,
            ns_variance=@ns_variance,
            tc_pos=@tc_pos,
            tc_cognizant=@tc_cognizant,
            tc_variance=@tc_variance,
            unique_row=CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(@business_date, '%d-%b-%y'),'_',@store,'_',@ns_pos,'_',@tc_pos),
            created_at=now()
        ", addslashes($value));

        if (DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($loadData)) {
            $response['status'] = 'success';
            //echo'tes';
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 'error';
            //echo'ayaw';
        }
    }
}else{
    //echo'wala nangyre';
}
```

What happening is the '%' having a problem with sprintf, so what I did is try it without sprintf but it throws an error of mysql syntax and I already tried to change the escape, enclosed and terminated still doesn't work.

Is there other alternative way to convert those date 'dd-mm-yy' to 'YYYY-mm-dd' or insert without sprintf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%%` for literal `%` characters in a `sprintf()` format string.

```
    $loadData = sprintf("
        LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' IGNORE INTO TABLE pos_vs_cognizant CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES  
        (
            @store, 
            @business_date, 
            @ns_pos, 
            @ns_cognizant, 
            @ns_variance, 
            @tc_pos, 
            @tc_cognizant, 
            @tc_variance
        ) 
        SET
        id=null,
        store=@store,
        business_date=STR_TO_DATE(@business_date, '%%d-%%b-%%y'),
        ns_pos=@ns_pos,
        ns_cognizant=@ns_cognizant,
        ns_variance=@ns_variance,
        tc_pos=@tc_pos,
        tc_cognizant=@tc_cognizant,
        tc_variance=@tc_variance,
        unique_row=CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(@business_date, '%%d-%%b-%%y'),'_',@store,'_',@ns_pos,'_',@tc_pos),
        created_at=now()
    ", addslashes($value));
```